# Offset top does not return the expected value

Tags: jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=400)    $('#jtop').show('slow');
    if($(this).scrollTop()<400) if($('#jtop').width()) $('#jtop').hide('slow');
});
```

I'm using the function to determine if someone scrolls down over 400 an toggling an image and it's working fine but when I try to get notified if someone reaches my footer's top position it doesn't return the expected value. I used offset().top but it alerts me when I scroll down to bottom 0. I just want to know when user is entering and leaving my footer. Hope someone will help me. Thanks in advance.
If you want to see it in action then here is the link [heera.it](http://heera.it)

Non working code

```
    var ftop=$('#footer').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function(e){
        if($(this).scrollTop()>=400)
        {
            $('#jtop').show('slow');
        }
        if($(this).scrollTop()<400)
        {
            if($('#jtop').width()) $('#jtop').hide('slow');
        }
        if($(this).scrollTop()>=ftop)   console.log('true');
        if($(this).scrollTop()<ftop)    console.log('false');
    });
```

Comment: We need to see your non-working code. Not your working code. How are you checking whether someone is at the footer?

Comment: Strange, that should work. If I enter $('#footer').offset().top; from console I get the proper height, 1700 something. Chris is correct though, you should add the viewport height. That code tells you when something goes off the top of the screen to do a show.

Comment: I'm confused too, whatever, I want to show an image when user crosses 400px and want to change that image if user reaches footer and again want to restore the previous image when user leaves the footer and want to hide the image when he/she less than 440px of scrollTop. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess, but your footer's top position is probably being calculated correctly already, so when calculating whether or not the footer has been reached would involve calculating whether or not the scroll height *and* the viewport height *together* reach the footer's top position.

That make sense? If the footer's top position is say 1000px away, the scroll height of the window together with the height of the viewport will tell if we've reached the footer. I've made the mistake of trying to equate *just* the scroll height value, which would only show if the footer had reached the top of the screen completely.

So to some code:

```
var footer_top = $("#footer").position().top;

$(window).scroll(function(e) {

    var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
    var viewport_height = $(this).height();

    if (scroll_top + viewport_height >= footer_top) {
        alert("Footer reached!");
    }

});
```

Hope this helps and makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. This is Chris' answer, just formatted with your code. So accept his if you are happy.

http://jsfiddle.net/eL4HR/

```
var ftop = $('#footer').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 400) {
        $('#jtop').show('slow');
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 400) {
        if ($('#jtop').width()) $('#jtop').hide('slow');
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() >= ftop) console.log('true');
    else console.log('false');
});
```

Comment: Yes I'm happy now and as you said I should accept Chris' answer, so I'll and it's fair enough. If possible can you explain the fact in an easy way, I'm very week on calculation. Thanks!